# How to get Watir to look for child elements

Tags: watir

I have the following divs

```
<div class="item" id="123" >
  <div class="sub_item">
     ...
     <p id="456">Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to come up with a Watir query to test it I came up with the following (I only need the first one)...

```
  def item_present?
    # @browser.divs(:id => /\d+/).divs.length > 0
    @browser.divs(:id => /\d+/)[0].paragraphs(:id => /\d+/).size
  end
```

I get an error

```
undefined method `paragraphs' for #<Watir::Div:0x5a428c3e>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match "p" elements, the method is:

- `p` for the first match or
- `ps` for all matches

So you could do:

```
@browser.divs(:id => '123')[0].ps(:id => '456').size
```

Given the method name, perhaps you actually want to be doing?

```
@browser.div(:id => '123').p(:id => '456').present?
```

Note that `divs(:id => '123')[0]` is the same as just `div(:id => '123')`.

Comment: Thanks I still need them as a collection I was just making it simple the actual query is a regex so it matches multiple.

Comment: It would help if you gave a more representative HTML sample and explain what you are trying to do. It is unclear if you are saying that there are multiple divs you want to search or just multiple ps.

Comment: Sorry it just didn't seem like important information since the problem wasn't arising from the regex expression. I can't post the actual expression (it would make things far too complicated) but I updated the original post with a more accurate example.

Comment: I am also noticing that these Page Object queries are taking a rather long time (granted lots of data) is there a way around this? Perl would parse the HTML a lot quicker. Probably a separate question though.

Comment: The first approach is usually to change to more specific locators. For example, using regexp can be quite slow since each element has to be inspected. Assuming that is not a feasible solution, a common solution has been to extract the html and parse it using Nokogiri. If you do not want to learn Nokogiri, you can use the [Watir-Nokogiri gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-nokogiri) (which I hacked together) that uses the Watir API to parse the HTML.